# issue in Replacing images in document directory and then showing changed image in tableview

Tags: ios, nsdocumentdirectory

i use following code for replacing images in document directory

```
 NSLog(@"%@",_selectedimage);
        if([self string:pathOfDocDic containsText:@"Test_"]){

            NSLog(@"_selectedName%@",_selectedimage);
            NSData* data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(selectionView1.image);
            [data writeToFile:_selectedName atomically:YES]; 

          // no need to change database cus path going be same
```

i just change image by putting new image with same directory path and same name. so after that images get changed in document directory

now problem is when i get back to table view images appear same as before in document directory images is changed but its not getting changed in table view if i close app and start again then it get changed how can i solve this problem?

Comment: can you paste the table view code . How are you loading the table ?

Comment: i cant my table view is so complex and large.

Comment: if you are changing the Image successfully in the the path then the issue is in table view code .

Comment: if i add new image then its working perfectly but when i replace image then its not working maybe there is something like app has loaded resource and when something get replaced with same name it doesnt know. and when we relaunch app then app know it i dont know just guessing things